# SSMS / TSQL - Insert multiple records for every record found in query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2016

I want to insert multiple records (two to be specific) with a unique ID for Column 1 (in both records created) for every record that matches a specific query criteria . The rest of the values for the insert should be pulled from the respective columns on the query. In the first insert Column2 will be the original value from Column1, and on the second insert Column2 will be the original value from Column2.

Ideally, what I'm after is:

```
FIND RECORDS THAT MEETS CRITERIA
FOR EACH RECORD
GENERATE GUID
INSERT TWO NEW RECORDS WITH GUID AS COLUMN1, AND REMAINING COULMNS FROM 
CURRENT RECORD FOUND

RECORDS
123 abc 3 4 5
456 def 6 7 8

RECORD 1
123 abc 3 4 5

NEW RECORDS AFTER INSERTS
UID1 123 3 4 5
UID1 abc 3 4 5

ROW 2
456 def 6 7 8

NEW RECORDS AFTER INSERTS
UID2 456 6 7 8
UID2 def 6 7 8
```

The below INSERT SELECT FROM handles exactly what I want to do but only for a single insert per record found.

```
INSERT INTO table1
( 
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3
    Column4
    Column5
)
SELECT
    NEWID(), -- unique ID
    Column2, -- or Column1 based on which insert we are doing
    Column3, -- always column 3
    Column4, --always column 4
    Column5 -- always column 5
FROM
    table1
WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL
AND Column1 != Column4
```

Is there an easy way to do this via TSQL? I need it to run in bulk, for a potential of thousands of records meeting the query conditions.

Comment: Do you want each pair of rows to have the same `NEWID`?

Comment: Yes the same generated ID per pair of records created. The goal here is to split the initial data into two records and use a generated ID to link the two together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH xQ(UUID,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5) AS 
( 
    SELECT
        NEWID(),
        Column1,
        Column2,
        Column3,
        Column4,
        Column5 
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL
    AND Column1 != Column4
)

INSERT INTO table1
( 
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    Column4,
    Column5
)
SELECT
    UUId, 
    Column1,
    Column3,
    Column4,
    Column5 
FROM xQ
UNION
SELECT
    UUId,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    Column4,
    Column5 
FROM xQ
```

Comment: This appears to generate a UUID for each record inserted. I guess i should clarify that this is really only "UNIQUE" per set of records inserted. One UUID for both inserts.  Otherwise it accomplished what I was going for. Can you explain to me what the with xQ statement is ? I did a quick search but couldn't find any documentation around it.

Comment: i used CTE (common table expression ) in sql server for generating unique ID for each record that return by criteria, then i using this result twice

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility. First use your query that generates the first set of rows and insert them into a temp table.

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/IPAG68747)**

```
SELECT 
    NEWID() AS [uid], -- unique ID
    column1,
    Column2, -- or Column1 based on which insert we are doing
    Column3, -- always column 3
    Column4, --always column 4
    Column5 -- always column 5
INTO #temp
FROM
    table1
WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL
AND Column1 != Column4
```

Now using that temp table we can do a `UNION` with the same table to generate the second set of rows and insert them into table1.

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT 
    [uid] AS Column1
  , CAST(column1 AS NVARCHAR(3)) AS Column2
  , column3 
  , column4
  , column5
FROM #temp
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    [uid] AS Column1
  , column2
  , column3 
  , column4
  , column5
FROM #temp
ORDER BY Column1

DROP TABLE #temp
```